# How to install Pulse Secure on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64 bit?

Tags: 22.04, vpn, 64-bit, lts

Pulse secure (9.1r1.0 and so on) installation works fine, but GUI isn't launching from App Icon.

How do I fix this?

Versions:

1. Pulse secure (ps-pulse-linux-9.1r1.0-b21-ubuntu-debian-32-bit-installer.deb and ps-pulse-linux-9.1r1.0-b21-ubuntu-debian-64-bit-installer.deb)
2. Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS 64-bit

Comment: This is the question body. add all this text to a answer.

Comment: Hi. This is a question and answer site. This looks like an answer to an unasked question. There needs to be a question first in order to give an answer.

Comment: @David could you point me to place where I can share Q and A and make it available for search (googlable)? I would appreciate that

Comment: No idea just not on this site.

Answer (score -1):

Source : The OP of this question
(This is from his perspective, not mine)

One can try to launch it using `sudo /usr/local/pulse/pulseUi` and see libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is missing.

To install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0, download of next packages is required:

[libwebkitgtk](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb)

[libjavascriptcoregtk](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb)

[libicu](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb)

[libwebp](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwebp/libwebp6_0.6.1-2_amd64.deb)

Download those packages using wget ... And install each package, in proper dependency tree order using: `sudo dpkg -i`

It worked for my set of versions:

Pulse secure (ps-pulse-linux-9.1r1.0-b21-ubuntu-debian-32-bit-installer.deb

and ps-pulse-linux-9.1r1.0-b21-ubuntu-debian-64-bit-installer.deb)
Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS 64-bit

Comment: I have splitted the question and answer, the trusted community have to do a pending confirmation of my edit to the question